# How to pass data class which implements an interface as parameter to an inherited function? [Kotlin]

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an interface like this.

```
interface MenuOption {
    val name: String
}
```

Another data class which implements the above.

```
data class XYZMenuOption (override val name: String) : MenuOption
```

I have a parent class like this.

```
class MenuWidget {
    fun listener (options: MenuOption) {}
}
```

And this second class inherits it. This class overrides the listener function but should take the implemented data class as parameter.

```
class XYZMenuWidget: MenuWidget {
   override fun listener (options: XYZMenuOption) {}
}
```

However, the problem is that I can't use XYZMenuOption as a replacement for MenuOption. My idea was that both MenuOption and MenuWidget be very generic and that I can implement them to suit specific menu options wherever needed.

Comment: you need to implement generics at class level and inside class maintainer list of option which are concrete implementer of that generic interface, i strongly recommend to make menu as abstract class instead of interface because by default menu has default functionality it is not just a contract which lays out some rule but a class with default behavior which can be extended to suit needs.

Comment: @silentsudo I can't see why I should use abstract class here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change parameter type when overriding parent function. You have 2 options in such case depending on what your end goal is:

1. Make use of generics in case you want your XYZMenuWidget to only accept XYZMenuOption:

   ```
   interface MenuOption {
      val name: String
   }

   data class XYZMenuOption (override val name: String) : MenuOption

   // You must make class open in other to extend from it
   open class MenuWidget<T : MenuOption> {

   // You must make function open in other to override!
       open fun listener (options: T) {}
   }

   class XYZMenuWidget(): MenuWidget<XYZMenuOption>() {
       // Listener now only accepts XYZMenuOption
       override fun listener (options: XYZMenuOption) {}
   }
   ```
2. Use same type as in parent class (in case you want listener to be called with any implementation of `MenuOption`:

   ```
   interface MenuOption {
       val name: String
   }

   data class XYZMenuOption (override val name: String) : MenuOption

   // You must make class open in other to extend from it
   open class MenuWidget {

       // You must make function open in other to override!
       open fun listener (options: MenuOption) {}
   }

   class XYZMenuWidget(): MenuWidget() {
       override fun listener (options: MenuOption) {}
   }
   ```

Comment: i am coming from oops bg, data class is just  a data holder class why we are making it implement interface?

Comment: @silentsudo Only difference between regular `class` and `data class` is that compiler can automatically create equals,hashcode,toString and copy functions so we can avoid writing boilerplate code, so it is completely fine for data class to implement interface.

Comment: In this case it makes perfect sense to use data class as it acts as exactly that, class that is used to pass data, interface defines that `name` is mandatory but XYZMenuOption could as well contain any other data, this allows to make well structured hierarchy in case of generic approach, as XYZMenuWidget will be fully aware that it is XYZMenuOption and would be able to access any additional properties if there were any.

Comment: @FilipRistic works like a charm. Also cleared my conceptual doubt, thanks!

Comment: @FilipRistic that description makes sense.